# How to replace all special characters in a string with spaces?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT 1.0.

Suppose I have a string similar to "apple-mango%also|there"

I am trying to replace all the non-alphanumeric characters with spaces.
I tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(., '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxysABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ''), ' ')"/>
```

but it didn't work.
The trouble is with the outer translate.

As i understand, in a `translate()` the length of the third string should be same as that of second string or else the missing characters will be taken to be replaced by an empty string (`''`).

The inner translate works fine since I want to remove all characters with an empty string anyways.

But the outer translate only replaces the first character of the second argument string with a space and replaces rest with an empty string.

Since my list of non-alphanumeric characters in the second argument of the outer translate is dynamic I can't pre-code the third argument.

ex:

My inner translate will return `-%|`. Which is correct.

Now my outer translate is `translate(., '-%|', ' ')`.

Which returns `apple mangoalsothere`.

How can it be done short of writing something like this:

```
translate(., '`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:'",<.>/?', '                                  ')
```

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with the first expression, as that will indeed replace all non-alphameric characters with a space. You really need to be specific about what you need to do, as there isn't really a definition of "special characters". Either you need to define exactly the characters you want to keep, or define exactly what characters you want to remove. Thank you!

Comment: The double-translate trick used in your attempt is designed precisely to handle the task: the inner translate produces a list of all the characters in the input after removing ascii alphanumerics, and the outer translate replaces all the characters in this list by spaces.

Comment: @TimC By special characters I meant non-alphanumeric characters. Please see the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a recursive template to create a string of nothing but spaces for a given length

```
<xsl:template name="AllSpaces">
    <xsl:param name="spaces" />
    <xsl:if test="$spaces > 0">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:call-template name="AllSpaces">
            <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="$spaces - 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you can generate a string with the number of spaces equal to the length of the string you are working with.

```
    <xsl:variable name="specialchars" select="translate(., '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '')" />
    <xsl:variable name="spaces">
        <xsl:call-template name="AllSpaces">
            <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="string-length($specialchars)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
```

You can then use this `spaces` variable in your translate. For example, try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:variable name="specialchars" select="translate(., '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '')" />
        <xsl:variable name="spaces">
            <xsl:call-template name="AllSpaces">
                <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="string-length($specialchars)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $specialchars, $spaces)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="AllSpaces">
        <xsl:param name="spaces" />
        <xsl:if test="$spaces > 0">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="AllSpaces">
                <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="$spaces - 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, if you had multiple strings you wanted to replace in your XML, you could slightly improve things by having a global variable for `spaces` that was equal to the length of the longest string. This would give you more spaces than you needed, but that would not be a problem.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:variable name="spaces">
        <xsl:for-each select="//data">
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(.)" order="descending" />
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:call-template name="AllSpaces">
                    <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="string-length(.)" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="data">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(., '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ''), $spaces)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="AllSpaces">
        <xsl:param name="spaces" />
        <xsl:if test="$spaces > 0">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="AllSpaces">
                <xsl:with-param name="spaces" select="$spaces - 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to this XML

```
<test>
    <data>apple-mango%also|there</data>
    <data>apple-mango%also|there!test</data>
</test>
```

The following is output

```
apple mango also there
apple mango also there test
```

Comment: **Note**: If you're using Xalan or libxslt, you can use the EXSLT `str:padding()` function to generate the required string of spaces.

Comment: Caveat: the last character of the alphabet is `z` - not another `s`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way you could look at this is to use the result of the "inner translate" - i.e the string containing all the unwanted characters - as a parameter in a named recursive template that would replace them, one-by-one, by a space:

**XML**

```
<input>alpha-bravo/charlie#delta...echo?foxtrot%golf|hotel india-juliet</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="input"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="translate(input, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiters"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$delimiters">
            <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="substring($delimiters, 1, 1)" /> 
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string, $delimiter)" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, $delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="delimiters" select="substring($delimiters, 2)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>alpha bravo charlie delta   echo foxtrot golf hotel india juliet</output>
```

Comment: excellent answer. really wish i could mark both as correct anwers